# jQuery select element that doesn't have ID or Class

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

For my Google Analytics tracking I want to know when someone clicks on the following piece of HTML;

```
<div style="...">Vragen?</div>
```

Since it doesn't have a `.class` or `#id` I don't know how to select this item. I can't add a Class or ID either since it's HTML generated by javascript from an outside source.

Otherwise it would simply be;

```
$j('#uniqueId').on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Can you put this division into some another division? like <div id="myid">  <div style="box-.... </div>

Comment: Can you not simply *add* an `id` (or `class`) to the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content changes, but you know the position of the div on the page, you can use something like:

```
$('#container div').eq(n).on('click', function() {
   //your code here
});
```

where `#container` is the page container and `n` is the zero index location of the div you want to target (relative to other divs in the container).

If there is no container, you can try:

```
$('body').find('div').eq(n).on('click', function() {
       //your code here
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$('div:contains("Vragen?")').on('click', function() {
    //your code
});
```

Comment: it's not compulsory that the content would be always Vragen?

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible to put that div into some another, then you can simple get it like below

```
<div id="myid">
   <div style=".....">Vragen?</div>
</div>

$(document).on('click','#myid > div',function(){
    alert('clicked');
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eyH33/